# SQL Server : sorting the values based on ID column

Tags: sql-server-2008

The input and the desired output is shown below

**Input**

```
id  Msg res time
--------------------
1   a1  8   11:14:00
1   qq  8   11:15:00
1   d1  8   11:16:00
1   e1  8   11:17:00
1   f1  8   11:18:00
1   h   4   11:19:00
1   i   4   11:20:00
1   m35 4   11:21:00
1   n   4   11:22:00
1   o   4   11:23:00
1   p0  4   11:23:00
2   a1  4   11:24:00
2   p0  4   11:25:00
2   qq  4   11:26:00
2   c   4   11:27:00
2   h   4   11:28:00
2   o   4   11:29:00
3   c   4   11:30:00
3   qq  4   11:31:00
3   e1  4   11:32:00
```

Desired output:

```
id  Msg res time
---------------------
1   a1  8   11:14:00
1   d1  8   11:16:00
1   e1  8   11:17:00
1   f1  8   11:18:00
1   h   4   11:19:00
1   i   4   11:20:00
1   p0  4   11:24:00
1   qq  8   11:15:00
1   m35 4   11:21:00
1   n   4   11:23:00
1   o   4   11:22:00
2   a1  4   11:24:00
2   c   4   11:27:00
2   h   4   11:28:00
2   p0  4   11:25:00
2   qq  4   11:26:00
2   o   4   11:29:00
3   c   4   11:30:00
3   e1  4   11:32:00
3   qq  4   11:31:00
```

The code is below

```
CREATE TABLE k (id int, Msg varchar(1000), result int, time time);

INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘a1’, ‘8’, ‘11:14:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘qq’, ‘8’, ‘11:15:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘d1’, ‘8’, ‘11:16:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘e1’, ‘8’, ‘11:17:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘f1’, ‘8’, ‘11:18:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘h’, ‘4’, ‘11:19:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘i’, ‘4’, ‘11:20:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘m35’, ‘4’, ‘11:21:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘n’, ‘4’, ‘11:22:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘o’, ‘4’, ‘11:23:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘1’, ‘p0’, ‘4’, ‘11:23:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘a1’, ‘4’, ‘11:24:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘p0’, ‘4’, ‘11:25:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘qq’, ‘4’, ‘11:26:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘c’, ‘4’, ‘11:27:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘h’, ‘4’, ‘11:28:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘2’, ‘o’, ‘4’, ‘11:29:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘3’, ‘c’, ‘4’, ‘11:30:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘3’, ‘qq’, ‘4’, ‘11:31:00’)
INSERT INTO k VALUES (‘3’, ‘e1’, ‘4’, ‘11:32:00’)

select *
from k 
order by
    case
       when Msg = ‘a1’ or Msg = ‘b1’ or Msg = ‘b0’ or Msg = ‘c’ or Msg = ‘d1’ or Msg = ‘e1’ or Msg = ‘f1’ or Msg = ‘g’ or Msg = ‘h’ or Msg = ‘i’ then 1
       when Msg = ‘p0’ then 2
       when Msg = ‘p1’ then 3
       when Msg = ‘qq’ then 4
       when Msg = ‘i’ then 5
       when Msg = ‘j’ then 6
       when Msg = ‘k0’ then 7
       when Msg = ‘k1’ then 8
       when Msg = ‘l’ then 9
       when Msg = ‘l1’ then 10
       else 11 
   end, Msg
```

But this code is not returning the desired output. In case if there is only one set of values in the ‘id’ column then it sorts the ‘Msg’ column accordingly as per the condition given in the code. But in the sample input there are 3 different sets of values in ‘id’ column (1,2 and 3). So when I execute the above code the sorting is done for the whole data. It is obvious because I did not give any conditions for grouping by ‘id’ column. Is there any solution to achieve the desired result? (Also I tried to fetch each line in the input table by using cursors but even there I was not able to put the conditions properly in the loop). Any help would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select * from k order by id, Msg
```

Basically, you already have the value of 'id' column and you want to order the result by two columns, first the Id and then the Msg; meaning the rows that have the same value in id, will be sorted by the value of Msg.